# Filtering data in Tableau using multi-select substring matches

Tags: tableau-api

I have data that contains a column containing various combinations of substrings.  Say the distinct values in this column are...

"A", "B", "C", "AB", "AC", "BC", "ABC"

I'd like to create a multi-selection filter with the values "A", "B" and "C".  The selected values will define a filter that selects data containing ANY of the selected substrings.  That is to say, I'm looking to create a filter that essential performs a union operation on the base substrings.

I'm a bit new to Tableau, so any advice on how to achieve this, or if it's even possible would be appreciated.

Comment: How many possible multi-select options will their be?  It seems a parameter may be helpful, but that cannot be multi-select so if it is just three you can set up three T/F parameters for each.  Another alternative would be a set that is dynamically change with a selection if their are multiple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contains filter equivalent in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635372/contains-filter-equivalent-in-tableau)